# Array not able to be called outside of while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, scope

How can I set `$sections` up so it works outside of the while loop?

```
while($sections = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $section_name = $sections['location'];
        $sections[$section_name] = $sections['content'];
        echo $sections['main'];
    }
```

`$sections['main']` echoes correctly here, but when I run it further down in the code (outside the while loop) it displays nothing. I assume this is something to do with the scope?

I've tried both `$sections = array();` and `$sections = '';` prior to the loop. Both don't solve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last iteration would null the $sections variable, thus breaking the while loop.

Comment: Yep. Fixed by changing the new array name to something else. Thanks.